# How to gracefully render React.js Components with ajax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, singlepage

I am working on a React.js app and all pages have components with some data that is fetched from an API, the problem is that all pages look weird when they load because the hardcoded text and design elements load first and when data is fetched everything gets filled in. Is there common way to do this in single page apps or specifically in React.js so the pages don't look weird while loading?

Comment: Hint: the same way you'd do it with any ajax setup, show a loading spinner :)

Comment: I do understand that but how would I stop all hard coded content on the page to not load while data is being fetched?

Comment: I've just added an example of how you can render the hard coded content only after the data has been successfully fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've recently had a similar problem and here is an outline of how we've approached it:

1) Add a `loading` key to state and initially set it to `true`
2) When the AJAX requests returns data, set `loading` to `false`
3) `In render()` method return a loading indicator / spinner when
    `loading` is `true`

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/ozaaPm and full code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      time: null,
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {  
    axios.get(this.props.url)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          time: response.data.time,
          loading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    let content;

    if (this.state.loading) {
      content = 'Loading...'
    } else {
      content = <p>Current time is: {this.state.time}</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App url={"http://date.jsontest.com/"} />,  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Sayayin, I've just updated my answer. Is this what you are after?

Comment: You are awesome! this is what I needed, I already tried and works! thank you!